# Use a Modal to Add an Item from a List in SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swiftui, swiftui-list

I would like to know how to add an item from a List included in a Modal so when I tap in a row, I can have the item selected in the First View that launched the sheet (to make clearer, the effect the you find when the iPhone app "Messages" select a contact from "Contacts").

Here's my basic code

```
struct Product : Hashable { 

  var name : String

  init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }

  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(name)
  }
}


class Manager {

  var product : [Product] = []

  init() {


    let pencil = Product(name: "Pencil")
    let eraser = Product(name: "Eraser")
    let ruler = Product(name: "Notebook")

    product = [pencil, eraser, ruler]

  }
}
```

---

```
struct FirstView: View {

  @State var isSheetOpened = false
  var products : Manager

  var body: some View {
      VStack {
      Button(action: {
          self.isSheetOpened.toggle()
      }) {
          Text("Add item from sheet")
      }
      .sheet(isPresented: self.$isSheetOpened) {
          Sheet(products: self.products, isSheetOpened: self.isSheetOpened)
      }

      Text("Add here")

    }
  }
}
```

---

```
struct Sheet: View {

  var products : Manager
  var isSheetOpened : Bool

  var body: some View {
      VStack {
          List {                
              ForEach(self.products.product, id: \.self) { index in
                Text(index.name)
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

check this out:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Product : Hashable {
    
    var name : String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(name)
    }
}


class Manager : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var chosenProducts : [Product] = []
    var products : [Product] = []
    
    init() {
        
        let pencil = Product(name: "Pencil")
        let eraser = Product(name: "Eraser")
        let ruler = Product(name: "Notebook")
        
        products = [pencil, eraser, ruler]
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var manager : Manager
    
    @State var isSheetOpened = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.isSheetOpened.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Add item from sheet")
            }
            Text("Chosen products")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            List {
                ForEach(self.manager.chosenProducts, id: \.self) { product in
                    Text(product.name)
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$isSheetOpened) {
                Sheet(isSheetOpened: self.$isSheetOpened)
                    .environmentObject(self.manager)
            }
            
            Text("Add here")
            
        }
    }
}

struct Sheet: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var manager : Manager
    
    @Binding var isSheetOpened : Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List (self.manager.products, id: \.self) { product in
                Button(action: {
                    self.manager.chosenProducts.append(product)
                    self.isSheetOpened = false
                }) {
                    Text(product.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(Manager())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. I'm an early programmer in SwiftUI and I'm developing my first app so it happens that I bump into some lacks of basic knowledge. I will use your code as a basis to expand my skills.

Answer (score 1):

1. You would need to use @State in FirstView and @Binding to Sheet to show the selected item in FirstView.
2. Additionally, to dismiss the view after selecting the item in the Sheet, you can use the environment variable presentationMode.

Here's the code that does it. Hope it helps.

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @State var isSheetOpened = false
    @State var selectedProduct: String = ""
    var products = Manager()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.isSheetOpened.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Add item from sheet")
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$isSheetOpened) {
                Sheet(products: self.products, isSheetOpened: self.isSheetOpened, selectedProduct: self.$selectedProduct)
            }

            Text("\(selectedProduct)")
        }
    }
}

struct Sheet: View {
    var products : Manager
    var isSheetOpened : Bool
    @Binding var selectedProduct: String
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(self.products.product, id: \.self) { index in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.selectedProduct = index.name
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }) {
                        Text(index.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Felix, you've been really helpful!